# Start function only if user has scrolled X pixels since function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using this bit of code to detect if #myDiv, which is in `position: sticky`, is currently pinned or not and add a class when it is:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv")

const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("sticky", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] }
);

observer.observe(myDiv);
```

It works like a charm but I have a big issue. When #myDiv, which is sticked to the bottom of the viewport, is not sticky anymore its height changes therefore triggering the above function and entering an infinite loop.

To fix this problem I want to limit the execution of my function to a condition: If the user has scrolled 200 pixels upward or downward since last execution of the function, the function can be executed again.

Thanks a lot for your help on this.

**edit: I've added a simplified version of my problem. You can see my issue by slowly scrolling to the point where #mydiv isn't pinned anymore.**

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv")

const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("sticky", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] }
);

observer.observe(myDiv);
```

```css
body{color:#333; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{background border:dashed 1px #333;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa;
}
.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

#mydiv{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; bottom:-1px; border-color:red;background: red;}
.content {font-size: 16px;padding:0;text-align: center}

#mydiv.sticky .content {display: none;}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <div id="mydiv">
  <p class="content">Content 1</p>
  <p class="content">Content 2</p>
  <p>MyDiv</p>
  </div>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</main>
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: you can use variable to keep track of last scroll position and compare it with current scroll position before executing function

Comment: Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52584084/2528232 I think you are interested in controling the thresholds if I understand you problem right.

Comment: Would be really helpful (for completeness) if you [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: @Valery Threshold and RootMargin can't help me here as #myDiv is sticky and is always visible on screen.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Indeed it is way better now, thx you.